# Adding tag for examples in scenario outline (behave)

Tags: python, selenium, python-behave

Is it possible to add tag for examples in scenario outline using behave? Something like this.

```
Examples:
  |input     |output    |
  @test1
  |one       |two       |
  @test2
  |three     |four      |
```

When I try to do this I get parser error: `Parser failure in state next_scenario, at line 15: 'Examples:'`

Comment: I think the |input|output| header needs to be repeated for both tables and should be below the tags you are using.

Comment: I've tried to put Examples: and |input|output| header before every example but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: What is the parser error

Comment: "Parser failure in state next_scenario, at line 15: 'Examples:'" if I'm trying to repeat headers every time. If not it crashes on first example.

Comment: check this out - https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/485, seems what you are attempting is not released officially but available.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is actually available on the development version of Behave, it just isn't available in the public release yet. See [this](https://github.com/behave/behave/issues/485) Github issue for more details.

Answer originally provided by [@Grasshopper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4512398/grasshopper) in comments.